# My code for piechart (d3) is not working, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For a class in data visualization i need to make a piechart in d3. I wrote the code, but after running on local server it does not work, but also does not show any errors.

I tried to code the chart according to some online examples and studied the elements of a pie chart. I cannot discover the bug in my code.

```
function draw_d3_piechart(input_data){
  // putting the datapoints in an array
  var data = {math: input_data["VALUE_MATH"], reading: 
     input_data["VALUE_READ"], science:input_data["VALUE_SCIENCE"]};

  console.log(data);
  // the output of this is :
  // {math: 387, reading: 398, science: 397}

  // determining the width, height
  var margin = {top: 50, right: 100, bottom: 0, left: 50},
    svgWidth = 500,
    svgHeight = 400,
    plotWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right,
    plotHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    radius = Math.min(svgWidth, svgHeight) / 2;


  // creating svg element in a div that is in the html file
  var svg = d3.select("#piechart_area"),
        width = svgWidth,
        height = svgHeight;

  // creating g element for the chart to be written in
  var g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + svgWidth / 2 + "," + 
                   svgHeight / 2 + ")");

  // creating colorscale
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
              .domain(data)
              .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888"]);

  // determining size of wedges
  var pie = d3.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function(d) {return d.value; });
  var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data));

  g
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(data_ready)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(0)
    .outerRadius(radius)
  )
  .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.data.key)) })
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", "2px")
  .style("opacity", 0.7);


};
```

The data looks like this for this specific example: 
{"LOCATION":"PER","SUBJECT":"TOT","TIME":2015,"VALUE_READ":398.0,"VALUE_MATH":387.0,"VALUE_SCIENCE":397.0,"TOTAL_VALUE":1182.0}

After calling this function, there is no output at all (except for the console.log which I used to test whether the data was in the right format). No errors either. I would appreciate if someone could send me in the right direction of what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you add your data?
And/or make an example in [jsFidle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I added the data that represents input_data in this case. In the end code of this assignment, the piechart is created by clicking on a bar of my already existing bar chart, that is why input_data is only one object.

Comment: You'll need to create a reproducible example.  I tried your [code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/q6pYSFGeZm6C9Ext9qHO?p=preview) and it works just fine...

Comment: @Mark That is interesting, thank you. Then I at least know it is not about this part of my code. The complete code also consists a function all for a bar chart, inside a promise.all().then(). Probably something goed wrong there then..

Comment: Well, I was going to answer with your code on a fiddle, but @Mark already submitted one (however I prefer jsfiddle)
Anyway, for the future, you can add library, by clicking on the side on ressources and typing the name you want (like d3) (like here https://jsfiddle.net/2j379ykL/1/)

Comment: @JackRed Thanks for the time just as well :)